# What is Qubit's equivalent to the Doctor's "Allons-y"?

Tags: comics, quotes, boom-studios, irredeemable

In the *Irredeemable* comic universe, at one point, Qubit uses a German phrase with a connotation very similar to the "Allons-y" used by the Doctor of Doctor Who.

What is that phrase, and in what issue of what series does he use it?

Comment: los geht's? 
lass uns gehen?

Comment: @sgfit  I have seen what seemslike hundeds of episodes of Dr. Who (all in the original English), and I don't remember the Doctor saying "Allons-y" and nor do I know what such a phrase would mean.  Possibly you spelled the Doctors phrase wrong, or maybe you watch Dr. Who dubbed into another language.

Comment: @M.A.Golding, it’s David Tennant's Doctor and you can find clips on YouTube using the spelling in the post. [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/allons-y) says it means "Let’s go!", which makes sense in the Doctor Who context, too.

Comment: "Allons-y" is a common French phrasing for "let's go"

Comment: @M.A.Golding The question does not ask what French phrase that The Doctor says; the question asks what German phrase that Qubit says.

Comment: Everything I remember about the panel:

• It was part of a flashback sequence.
• Qubit was running from right to left, into a portal.
• The phrase was one word, four or five syllables, began with 'A' and ended with 'T'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reread the entire series.  Turns out I didn't have to read far.

The answer is "Ausgezeichnet" (meaning 'Excellent'), first used in Irredeemable, issue 4.